# How to show List as table in spring mvc form

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
public class Parent {

    private Integer Id;
    private String  name;
    private String age;
    private List<Childrens> childrens;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My JSP classs:

```
<spring:bind path="parent.*">
    <c:if test="${not empty status.errorMessages}">
        <div class="error">
            <c:forEach var="error" items="${status.errorMessages}">
            <img src="<c:url value="/images/iconWarning.gif"/>"
                alt="<fmt:message key="icon.warning"/>" class="icon" />
            <c:out value="${error}" escapeXml="false" />
            <br />
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form:form commandName="parent" method="post"
        action="parent .html" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)"
        id="parentForm">

        <appfuse:label styleClass="desc" key="name" />
        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="fieldError" />
        <form:input path="name" id="name" cssClass="text medium" 
            readonly="true" cssErrorClass="text medium error" />

        <appfuse:label styleClass="desc" key="age" />
        <form:errors path="age" cssClass="fieldError" />
        <form:input path="age" id="cage" cssClass="text medium" 
            readonly="true" cssErrorClass="text medium error" />
```

I want  show list of `Children`s as a table. How can I do it? A list inside form page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to use the built-in jstl tag lib (which you already) to declare the bean and get the list of children and iterate over them with "forEach".

Using spring form tag doesn't prevent you from doing this as far as I know.